# XSL For Each - Path

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file looks like below

```
- <alert>
   - <adv_details>
      <type>Primary Type</type> 
      <name>Some Name</name> 
      <id>ID Num</id>
     <adv_details>
     .....
  <alert>
```

My XSL looks like this

```
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size"><xsl:value-of select="$font-size"/></xsl:attribute>
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:for-each select="//alert">         
        <xsl:call-template name="alert_details">
            <xsl:with-param name="xmlSection" select="./alert_details"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      ......
```

Then I try to reach each value of the element inside the node `<adv_details>`.
First I declare this template name `<xsl:template name="alert_details">`and the whole code is

```
<xsl:template name="alert_details">
<fo:table>
   <fo:table-body>
      <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block > 
                <xsl:value-of select="./@type"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block >
                <xsl:value-of select="./@name"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block >
                <xsl:value-of select="./id"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
   </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
</xsl:template>
```

It doesn't show the values! 
I thought it is a right way.  first, I have for-each select="//alert, then I have `<xsl:with-param name="xmlSection" select="./alert_details"/>` and lastly, I select each node inside alert_details, but somehow the values don't show up.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template, context node (= the `.` expression) is the `<alert>` element.
In fact you want to query the type child element of the xmlSection parameter.
So, declare explicitly the parameter xmlSection in your template:

```
<xsl:template name="alert_details">
  <xsl:param name="xmlSection"/>
  ...
```

And use it in your selection:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$xmlSection/type"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, NLips! Please make me more clear that we don't need to have `<xsl:with-param name="xmlSection" select="./alert_details"/>